# iOS 13 Changes to UISearchBar tint's, can't achieve the same outcome

Tags: xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, ios13

I've been experimenting all day and trying to figure out just how to get my UISearchBar to appear the same in iOS13 as it appears in iOS12/11

So the way the search bar is added is simply a new UISearchController.

```
            var searchController = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null);
            searchController.SearchBar.Placeholder = "Search";
            searchController.SearchResultsUpdater = this;
            searchController.HidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;
            searchController.DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;

            NavigationItem.SearchController = searchController;
            NavigationItem.HidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false;
```

The results on iOS 11/12:

[image: iOS11/iOS12]

The results on iOS 13:

[image: iOS13]

On iOS 13 I am using the new UINavigationBarAppearance code like this:

```
                var appearance = new UINavigationBarAppearance();
                appearance.ConfigureWithOpaqueBackground();
                appearance.BackgroundColor = ColorPalette.TintColor;
                appearance.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes { ForegroundColor = UIColor.White };

                NavigationItem.StandardAppearance = appearance;
```

On iOS 11/12 I am using legacy way to achieve it:

```
                NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
                NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
                NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = ColorPalette.TintColor;
                NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
```

I've tried a number of things, but can't seem to get the UISearchBar to tint by itself how iOS11/12 achieves it.

I know that the new UISearchBar now has access to the UITextField and I can configure the background color's etc.

Comment: Yeah, It seems that Apple only recommends the searchbar with a light background, and the display effect on a light background can be. Finally , `BarTintColor` seems not work in IOS 13.

Comment: What baffles me is I can't find documentation on this at all

Comment: Yeah, Apple's documentation of the new method is too little .I have submitted it to GitHub [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7846). If have silution will update there , you can follow it up.

Comment: Having this same issue right now, glad someone else noticed this too lol.

Comment: Did anyone found the solution to this issue? Please share here if you have found it.

Comment: I am looking for solution of the same problem. Are there any updates on this from anyone?

Comment: The same problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
```

The code above has a side effect which removes corner radius of the text field.

Extension

```
extension UISearchBar {
  /// This solves iOS 13 issue which is a light gray overay covers the textField.
  /// - Parameter color: A color for searchField
  func setSearchFieldBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor) {
    searchTextField.backgroundColor = color
    setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
    // Make up the default cornerRadius changed by `setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(_:for:)`
    searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    searchTextField.clipsToBounds = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There were several properties added in iOS 13, so you need to use them with the help of a conditional. For changing the background color, you have to use the `BackgroundColor` property of the `SearchBar`, like this

```
searchController.SearchBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom renderer and override the OnElementChanged method this way

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
{
  base.OnElementChanged(e);
  if (Control != null)
  {
    if(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13,0))
      Control.SearchTextField.BackgroundColor = Element.BackgroundColor.ToUIColor();
  }
}
```

later on, you don't have to do anything else and worked for me on ios 12 and ios 13+

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 13, you have access to the internal `UISearchTextField` through the `SearchTextField` property, you can set it's background directly (in my case, I need the background to be white). Be sure to check the iOS version to avoid exceptions.

```
if(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13,0))
{
    searchController.SearchBar.SearchTextField.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired result by adding couple of lines.

> searchBar.barTintColor =  UIColor.red 
> searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

Before you try this code please link IB Outlets for searchBar

> @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!