# Xamarin Forms Searchbar iOS 13 ignores background color

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

It seems the latest version of iOS (13) ignores the searchbar background color?

[iOS 13 Changes to UISearchBar tint's, can't achieve the same outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229829/ios-13-changes-to-uisearchbar-tints-cant-achieve-the-same-outcome)

I'm using this and it works on all versions below, but on 13 it ignores the background color and makes it white

```
  <SearchBar HeightRequest="35" BackgroundColor="#2A4880" TextColor="White"></SearchBar>
```

Is this a known issue?  Is there a work around?

Comment: Unfortunately , this should be the problem of Apple . Because even it can not work when using `Xcoed` to set color for `SearchBar`.

Comment: Yes I agree.  Not sure if Xamarin has handled it or not

Comment: I have submitted an issue in GitHub , however it be closed ...Maybe need someone submit to Apple first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by creating a [**PlatformEffect**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction):

**App.xaml.cs**

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("ProjectName")]
namespace ProjectName.App
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        ...
```

**Shared project:**

```
public class SearchBarBackgroundEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public SearchBarBackgroundEffect() : base("ProjectName.SearchBarBackgroundEffect") { }
    }
```

**iOS project:**

```
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(SearchBarBackgroundPlatformEffect), "SearchBarBackgroundEffect")]
 public class SearchBarBackgroundPlatformEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        private UISearchBar NativeSearchBar => (UISearchBar)Control;
        private SearchBar XamarinSearchBar => (SearchBar)Element;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
                NativeSearchBar.SearchTextField.BackgroundColor = XamarinSearchBar.BackgroundColor.ToUIColor();
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
             // Intentionally left blank.
        }
    }
```

**XAML File**

```
 <SearchBar>
                <SearchBar.Effects>
                    <effects:SearchBarBackgroundEffect />
                </SearchBar.Effects>
            </SearchBar>
```

Comment: sorry, how do you implement this?

Comment: @PatrickGoode A guide to implement platform effects can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/creating

Comment: any idea how to accomplish this using the Shell.SearchHandler class? It doesn't expose the SearchBar itself so you can't attach the effect to it.

Comment: @Shaggy13spe, then I would use a custom renderer on the default Xamarin.Forms SearchBar.

Comment: @Trevi Awater Which part is above, the part that goes into the shared project or the part that goes into the ios project?  if the above code is the part you put in the iOS project then I can't get it to recognize all of the classes used.  Can you please post a complete implementation, then I'll mark as answer if it works.  thanks

Comment: @Trevi Awater  Just an FYI, I implemented this and it didn't work

Comment: am i getting the "[assembly: ExportEffect" incorrrect?  What are you putting there.  When I decorate the project with [assembly: ResolutionGroupName("xxxx")] the app crashes on start

Comment: @TreviAwater Thanks again!  I got it to work after upgrading Xamarin and VS.  Also, I had the [assembly: ResolutionGroupName("myappnamehere")] declared in the wrong spot

Comment: This changes the color of the textfield not the surrounding grey area.

Comment: To change the grey surrounding area i'ts `Control.BarTintColor = Control.BarTintColor = UIColor.SomeColor;`

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing this issue, this definitely is a bug that needs to be fixed by Xamarin Forms.

It was introduced in iOS 13 when a new Property was introduced. As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58297436/11104068), they have to place a conditional check for iOS 13 and set the `BackgroundColor` of the `SearchBar`.

You could open an issue in Xamarin Forms on GitHub, and for now use a CustomRenderer to fix this locally.

Answer (score 0):

The issue on GitHub is https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8041

The simplest renderer with fix

```
using App.Mobile.iOS.CustomRenderers;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SearchBar), typeof(FixedSearchBarRenderer))]
namespace App.Mobile.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class FixedSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0) && Control != null)
            {
                Control.SearchTextField.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 255, 255);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in IOS 13, check out the Github discussion on this bug

```
UISearchBar.SearchTextField.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
```

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8041#issuecomment-544658047